# Polylang post_translations key

Tags: posts, translation, import, plugin-polylang

How does Polylang generate the post_translations key value that it uses to group the original with the translations? I need to make an import with custom posts and their translations, but I can't get them already associated, I tried to add an unique "post_translations" key to all those translations but nothing happened.

Comment: Polylang and other 3rd party plugin dev support questions are offtopic and not in this stacks scope.